# Converting a C# string array into a Javascript array

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

I am passing a C# string array into a method that is using TagBuilder to build some Javascript.  I don't seem to be able to get at the actual items within the array in my Javascript :

```
public static IHtmlString NewsTicker(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string[] arrTickerContents)
    {
        TagBuilder script = new TagBuilder("script");
        script.Attributes.Add("type", "text/javascript");

        script.InnerHtml = @"

            var rss_scr_contents = new Array();

            $.each('" + arrTickerContents + @"', function (i, objValue) {
                rss_scr_contents[i] = objValue;
        });

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(script.ToString());
    }
```

This results in the following source code :

```
var rss_scr_contents = new Array();

            $.each('System.String[]', function (i, objValue) {
                rss_scr_contents[i] = objValue;
        });
```

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `arrTickerCountents.ToString()` does not return the expected results.

For example, `(new [] {"hello", "world"}).ToString()` evaluates to `"System.String[]"`, which is not useful here.

A valid way to handle this is to use a convert than can emit a valid JavaScript value from a suitable .NET object - the most common tool is likely a JSON converter. I like [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx), but this should work with other converters.

```
var jsonArray = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrTickerContents);
script.InnerHtml = @"
        var rss_scr_contents = [];
        $.each(" + jsonArray + @", function (i, objValue) {
            rss_scr_contents[i] = objValue;
        })
"; // Please make sure to post valid code
```

Since the above loop does no processing as it stands, consider the simpler alternative. (I prefer to not use `var` with global window properties.)

```
script.InnerHtml = @"rss_scr_contents = " + jsonArray + ";";
```

I recommend JSON for its simpleness and available automatic conversions, although it may not always be applicable. Manually building a JavaScript value (i.e. without a JSON library) should be done with care as it is rather easy to introduce invalid, malicious, or otherwise unexpected output.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than hand-rolling your own solution, I'd recommend usinga library like Newtonsoft.Json.

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

I did it in `Razor` like this with `NewtonSoft`.

```
var jsonArray=Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arrTickerContents);
var rss_scr_contents = @Html.Raw(jsonArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each('[' + string.Join(',', arrTickerContents), + ']', function (i, objValue) {
```

Comment: -1 because while this *might* work it is really no better than not using placeholders in SQL. There is no guarantee that this manual to-JS-array will produce a valid literal, and the input isn't even as restricted as `int[]` so it could break for *many* (and perhaps most) values in the given input. I recommend just using "to JSON".

Comment: @pst, ummm... this is what was asked, this what was answered, of course, you can downvote though it's weird...

Comment: Re-read my comment. Here is some invalid output this code could generate: `[1,hello world!,alert("\o/")]]`.

Comment: First of all, I assume you meant `$.each('[' + string.Join(',', arrTickerContents) + @']', function (i, objValue) {`.  But even if you did, assume your input array was ["one", "two", "three"], this would result in `$.each('['"one, two, three"']', function (i, objValue) {`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @ScottMermelstein, no, why would it?!

Comment: You're within an @ string in the C#, so the ' is part of the string.  string.Join on an array will add commas, but not make them three different strings.  And as your solution stands right now, the , after `arrTickerContnets)` should cause a compile error.

Comment: Sorry, I should take back the double quotes I put in.  If your line was `$.each('[' + string.Join(',', arrTickerContents) + @']', function (i, objValue) {` I believe it would produce `$.each('['one, two, three']', function (i, objValue) {` .  I thought the strings each needed to have '' or "" around them when defining the javascript array.